# How to assign a value from an enum type

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I googled as best as I could anad found things like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html, but no answer to my specific question.

I have an enum that is being generated by typescript-generator. Here is the enum:

```
type OptionGroup = "ADMISSION_SOURCE" | "ADMISSION_TYPE" | "LEVEL_OF_URGENCY";
```

Now I want to assign it to a value in a structure, like this:

```
someConfig: DependantConfig = {
    noteRequired: false,
    optionGroup: , //here
    optionValueId: ''
};
```

How do I do this? I've tried several variations, but can't find the magic one.

Comment: `type` != `enum`? You can create a new name for a type of `enum` via type alias (`type`). [more info scroll to type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) what you are doing is string literal types.

Comment: That's a string literal type, not an enum. An enum is defined by using the keyword `enum`, which isn't used in your case.

Comment: I'm not surprised. This is what happens to enums, though, with typescript-generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was simply:

```
    optionGroup: 'IP_ADMISSION_SOURCE',
```

How about that?